# Wait for "last" event to fire

Tags: c#, .net, events, asynchronous, async-await

I need to block execution of my code until a user enters something into a `TextBox`.

However, in this particular case, I actually need to wait "until the user has finished typing". I.e., I don't want to just wait for the first time that the `TextChanged` event fires, I want to wait until at least 500ms have passed since the last time it fired before continuing the execution of my method.

Currently I have something that uses timers where every time the `TextChanged` event fires the timer is restarted and when the timer's `Tick` event fires it means that the user "has finished typing".

There are three main problems with this approach right now though:

- There has to be a better/cleaner way than using a `Timer` for this
- Up until now I did not need to block execution until the user "has finished typing", so was basically just adding my code to the `Tick` event handler, that's not changed though.
- I need to set a timeout as well, so that if the user hasn't finished typing in a certain amount of time, it should just return back to the method as having failed to wait for the user.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

This is very easy to do using [ReactiveUI](http://reactiveui.net/). Look at the example on the main page. It does more or less exactly what you are after.

It is based on [Reactive Extensions (RX)](https://rx.codeplex.com/) for .Net and is written to make things like these easy. If using ReactiveUI is not an option then I suggest you look at RX and how ReactiveUI implements this.

Comment: Can you provide an example of how this would work in my case? Also for posterity, the example on their page may change.

Comment: Good point. I only have my mobile here so my editing options are limited. The final block of code in the example listens to a changed value and waits one second before triggering a command. It should be easy to change a value in your view model from the TextChanged event to do something similar.

Comment: Would also welcome some answers that do not rely on ReactiveUI. It's something I haven't quite looked at yet and not sure if this is an option.

Comment: Well, you could look at using just rx itself. It is a nice library as well

Comment: The point I'm trying to make is that there's a lot of things I could do, but the reason why I'm asking it here is because I'm unaware of them and I can't accept an answer as vague as yours as the correct one. You're pointing me in "a" right direction, that is true, but imho the answer you provided so far does not contain enough info to be more than a comment rather than an actual answer. I'm just asking you to elaborate with examples specific to my particular scenario. I need to understand how the code comes together for my requirements, using both ReactiveUI and Rx.